# Moran's I in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I am doing a project that is looking at NDVI in certain areas of Africa in Google Earth Engine. I want to take the areas where I have made an NDVI band and then calculate Moran's I so that I can export it to my datasheet. I know how to export it, but I have found no documentation on how to calculate Moran's I within Google Earth Engine. Can it be done? Or will I have to export the data out to R or Python and calculate it there? If so, how do I go about doing that?